# How to append code to Uls with same class if height of UL is greater than X?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page with multiple same class ULs (c-params__list), Some of this Uls height are greater than 400 and some of them less than 400.

I need to append some code to Uls that have height greater than 400.

This is my code so far with no luck:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".c-params__list").each(function() {
      var height = this.height;
          if ( height > 400){
            $("ul.c-params__list").append('<div class="loadMore"><a class="load-More">More</a></div>');
        }
    });
});
```

This code does not append anything to any UL. What should i do?

Comment: if you add `console.log(height);` before `if`, does it log correct heights?

Comment: $(this) instead of **this** may solve the issue.

Comment: @AsfanShaikh Did you edit the solution _into the question_?

Comment: @ModusTollens (x)he did :)

Comment: @GrafiCode I'll roll it back then :)

Comment: @ModusTollens I must say, AsfanShaikh posted an answer too (identical to the edited question), than (x)he removed it after making (x)him notice

Comment: @GrafiCode That's still no reason for them to change the question :)

Comment: @ModusTollens I absolutely agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer that worked by @AsfanShaikh:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".c-params__list").each(function() {
      var height = $(this).innerHeight();
      if ( height > 400){
            $(this).append('<div class="loadMore"><a class="load-More">More</a></div>');
        }
    });
});
```